# how to implement single sign-on for multiple Web applications based on JAAS(Authorization)

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, jaas

I  started working on JAAS with SSO,I have some doubt about JAAS. JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization Service) framework to cater to multiple authentication mechanisms. The SSO server validates sign-on information against its own database or an external directory server and returns the session context and list of applications that the signed-on user can execute.Here  i  want to implement one more web application's.As per my knowledge the SSO JAAS  will return Session context. In my client web applications  already, i have  acegi security for authentication, using my acegi security  how can i  get  the session context from my SSO JAAS  for Authorization.I am trying to find out any configuration  sample , but still I did't get any work around example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [spring security configuration](http://code.google.com/p/kexamples/source/browse/trunk/jasig/springclient/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml?r=7). It is not exactly what you want but it will show you the way

Key points

- Check how authentication-manager is defined by using
  PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider. The preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService property defines a bean that will allow you to create your spring security UserDetails object from the JAAS Authentication object
- The j2eePreAuthFilter filter is the one that will delegate security from JAAS to spring security.

The rest is standard spring security configuration

Hope it helps a bit

Comment: enterlezi ,I  understood the  concept , can you give me more comments for  third party web application JAAS implementation